# Accessing Data cell value in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview containing details of ticket types and prices which the gridview gets from the database. In my Default.aspx.vb file I want to access the price value for a specific ticket but I cant figure out how to do it. My GridView looks like this:

Ticket Prices 
price_ID type    peak_offpeak   cost

1        Adult   peak           10.00

2        Adult   offpeak         5.00

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for your time
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I discovered this is what I needed incase anybody else has the same question:

Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(1)

```
        adult_price = row.Cells(3).Text
```

J